# find . .[^.]* -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sudo chmod 664; does not work

Tags: find, chmod, xargs

I am using this command to set permissions for files recursively

```
clime@vm6879 /srv/www-php/steeltrading $ find . .[^.]* -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sudo chmod 664
```

But after executing that command permissions of some files (most of them) are still not changed.

```
clime@vm6879 /srv/www-php/steeltrading $ ll media/xmlconnect/system/ok.gif 
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 www www 295 Jul  5  2012 media/xmlconnect/system/ok.gif
```

If I run just `find` to look if the file is in the list, I can see it:

```
clime@vm6879 /srv/www-php/steeltrading $ find . .[^.]* -type f | grep ok.gif
./media/xmlconnect/custom/ok.gif
./media/xmlconnect/original/ok.gif
./media/xmlconnect/system/ok.gif
```

If I move into directory media a run the command again, the file finally gets the right permissions.

```
clime@vm6879 /srv/www-php/steeltrading $ cd media/
clime@vm6879 /srv/www-php/steeltrading/media $ find . .[^.]* -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sudo chmod 664
clime@vm6879 /srv/www-php/steeltrading/media $ ll xmlconnect/system/ok.gif 
-rw-rw-r--. 1 www www 295 Jul  5  2012 xmlconnect/system/ok.gif
```

It looks like `sudo chmod 664` is not performed for some files and it seems that `xargs` is the problem but It is strange (no error messages). Any idea what might be the cause, please?

EDIT: Or maybe piping lots of data might be a problem?

Comment: Here's a little trick to quickly get data from any point in a series of pipes: `find . 'type f | tee /dev/stderr | xargs command`. That will write the output of the find command to `stderr` and `stdout`. `stderr` goes straight to the console and `stdout` is piped to `xargs`.

Comment: Try using `find`'s `-exec` option: `find . .[^.]* -type f -exec sudo chmod 664 -- '{}' \;`.

Comment: You might be passing too many arguments to `chmod`. Try `xargs -n5` to only allow 5 arguments per command.

Comment: the variant with -exec works, and the command execution is much longer. It seems that my original command crashes somewhere in the process.

Comment: `-n5` worked for my original command! And with -n100 it still works and is also fast. Thank you! If you could make that an answer...

Comment: What is `ll` an alias for? does it include `ls -L` by any chance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`find` will not skip dot files, so `.[^.]*` (`.[!.]*` in standard syntax) is redundant and will cause those files to be processed twice (and directories to be descended twice). (also note that `.[!.]*` misses files called `..foo` for instance).

However, `find` by default, does not descend into symlinks to directories. So if `media` is a symlink to an area outside `.`, files in there will not be processed.

You can use `-L` to tell find to follow symlinks. Note however that it will also cause `chmod` to be called for files that are symlinks to regular files.

```
sudo find -L . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} +
```

Or with some `find`/`xargs` implementations:

```
find -L . -type f -print0 | sudo xargs -r0 chmod 664
```

Contrary to what has been said here, `xargs` and `find -exec +` will take care of splitting the list of arguments to `chmod` if it's too big.

However it should be noted that the limit we're talking about here is the cumulative size of the arguments and environment passed to a command (to the `execve(2)` system call).

`find` and `xargs` will make sure that that limit is not reached (and leave a little margin), but if you run it as:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -r0 sudo chmod 644
```

instead of:

```
find . -type f -print0 | sudo xargs -r0 chmod 644
```

The `sudo` command (called by `xargs`) will receive all the arguments to pass to `chmod` and will also pass a `SUDO_COMMAND` environment variable to `chmod` that contains the list of files another time, so it will about double the size of arg+env passed to `chmod` and would explain why the limit is exceeded.

Comment: You are right about that `.[^.]*` being redundant but there is not a symlink on the path to to that file. As I pointed out the file is being found by find and adding -n5 solved that problem. Also I didn't mention that but even files in the current directory were untouched. I am sure that the command was exiting prematurely. If I try to run the same command with the same data on another system, I get `sudo: unable to execute /bin/chmod: Argument list too long` Strangely I did not get this error on the system in question.

Comment: @clime, yes, see how that error is reported by `sudo` and not by `find`. See the update to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the argument string you are passing to `chmod` is too long. You have a few options here.

**Using find's exec option**

When used with a semicolon, find's exec option will run a command once per file it finds: `find . .[^.]* -type f -exec sudo chmod 664 -- '{}' \;`.

**Limiting the number of arguments with xargs**

`xargs -n5` will pass a maximum of five arguments per command instance. You could also use the `-s` flag to limit the number of characters passed to the command: `xargs -s4096`. You can increase the limits for better performance; just be careful not to go to high.

**Recursive chmod**

`chmod` has a recursive option. This will affect directories as well as files though. If you are concerned about unsetting the execution bits on directories, you can run `chmod -R +X` (note the uppercase `X`) after you run your first command to recursively set the execution bits of your directories.

Comment: `xargs` takes care of not passing a too long argument string. On the face of the question (which I'm betting is incomplete: there's probably a symlink involved somewhere) none of what you propose would make a difference.

Comment: At least I was close. In the future, I will do more research before posting answers.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see what you are trying to do with the directory name .[^.]* (I think it's redundant) and I don't think you need -print0 -0 options, I suspect you are getting a buffer overflow somewhere pipe or command line size

try

```
find . -f file  -xargs chmod {}\;
```

You could use -v on chmod to see ech file being changed.

Comment: `.[^.]*` includes hidden files and directories but not .. directory. -print0 and -0 options are useful if you have got filenames with spaces. It was not buffer overflow. It was just some limit on how many parameters chmod accepts (the rest is probably trashed).